# How to align only the 2nd and 4th column of a table?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, alignment, multiple-columns

I know how to align all fields in a table:

```
r=["this is my text of line1", 
   "and this was one more line", 
   "another line of text to display"]

 import re
 splitter = "\s+"
 columnstotal = []
 for i in range(0,len(r)):
     #remove splitter
     columns = re.split(splitter, r[I])
     #keep splitter
     columns = re.split('(' + splitter + ')', r[i])
     columnstotal.append(columns)
```

and to display the columns again using .format()

but how do I align only 2 columns:
column 2 (right aligned) + columns 4 (left aligned)?

**Expected output**:

```
     this is| my  |text of line1
    and this| was |one more line
another line| of  |text to display
```

Comment: Please give more input data, and the exact result you would like to see as an output.

Comment: Also,a s a side note, perceive that if you wants parts of `r` you don't do a numerical  `for`  on the length of `r` in Python: you can simply do `for part in r:`

Comment: @jsbueno, I updated my question

Comment: @jsbueno, are you still there?

Answer (score 1):

Your splitter doesn't split into 3/4 parts... and your example shows 3 columns.
So assuming you fix your splitter and end up with:

```
columnstotal = [['this is', 'my', 'text of line1'],
                ['and this', 'was', 'one more line'],
                ['another line', 'of', 'text to display']]
width0 = max(len(d[0]) for d in s)
width1 = max(len(d[1]) for d in s)
for row in columnstotal:
    print("{:>{width0}}| {:<{width1}} |{}".format(*row, width0=width0, width1=width1))
```

Output:

```
     this is| my  |text of line1
    and this| was |one more line
another line| of  |text to display
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My splitter is the one to use. I have text lines that I want to divide. My problem is that I don't know how to obtain the columnstotal as in your answer. Do you know how to split a line at the 2nd and 4th occurrence of "\s+"? Btw thanks for the rest of your answer.